# Rails i18n list of items and looping in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

How can I list elements in my `yml` and loop through them in the view and access their properties? My current code only gets the last item in the list. I want to loop through in the view the list of items and display their `title` and `description` elements.

e.g.

yml:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  front_page:
    index:
      description_section:
        title: "MyTitle"
        items:
          item:
            title: "first item"
            description: "a random description"
          item:
            title: "second item"
            description: "another item description"
```

view:

```
      <%= t('front_page.index.description_section.items')do |item| %>
          <%= item.title %>
          <%= item.description %>
      <%end %>
```

Result:

```
   {:item=>{:title=>"second item", :description=>"another item description"}}
```

Desired Result:

```
    first item
    a random description

    second item
    another item description
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<% t('front_page.index.description_section.items').each do |item| %>
# ^ no equal sign here
  <%= item[:title] %>
     #^^^^ this is a hash
  <%= item[:description] %>
<% end %>
```

Also, your items list is not defined properly:

```
t('front_page.index.description_section.items.item.title')
# => returns "second item" because the key `item` has been overwritten
```

Use the following syntax to define an array in YAML:

```
items:
- title: "first item"
  description: "a random description"
- title: "second item"
  description: "another item description"
```

To check this, you can do in your IRB console:

```
h = {:items=>[{:title=>"first item", :description=>"desc1"}, {:title=>"second item", :description=>"desc2"}]} 
puts h.to_yaml
# => returns
---
:items:
- :title: first item
  :description: desc1
- :title: second item
  :description: desc2
```

Comment: Yes! That did it. Ran great. I had to add a `.each`  for it to loop properly.